# Как изменить baseUrl в springfox swagger

Tags: spring, swagger

Я использую Springfox Swagger2 со Swagger UI.

Swagger UI доступен по ссылке

```
http://localhost:8090/swagger-ui/
```

Как мне изменить этот адрес на другой, например:

```
http://localhost:8090/my/custom/path/swagger-ui/
```

Мои настройки:

```java
@EnableSwagger2
public class Configuration {

    @Bean
    public Docket api() { 
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)  
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("my.favorite.package"))
                .paths(PathSelectors.any())
                .build()
                .apiInfo(apiInfo()).useDefaultResponseMessages(false);
    }

    private ApiInfo apiInfo() {
        return new ApiInfoBuilder().title("My title").version("1.0")
                 .contact(new Contact("Blah", "blah.com", "blah@blah.com")).build();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Я нашёл решение для Springfox версии 3.0.0 [тут](https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/2250#issuecomment-667454685):

```yml
springfox:
  documentation:
    swaggerUi:
      baseUrl: /documentation
    openApi:
      v3:
        path: /documentation/v3/api-docs
    swagger:
      v2:
        path: /documentation/v2/api-docs
```

Конфигурация выше изменит URL на

`http://localhost:8090/documentation/swagger-ui/`

без всяких редиректов и костылей.

К сожалению, я не смог больше нигде найти упоминания этого решения,
в документации его не было. Но оно работает.

Comment: в Docket есть метод .host("") где можно указать путь. Но всё равно это получается как костыль - надо указывать жёстко. Если не указать - то берется по-умолчанию

Comment: Решение выше единственное, за исключением редиректов, host() указывает не путь к swagger-ui, а хост для использования в test-запросах, что другое